# Meaning of (function($) { })(jQuery) (e.g., in jQuery Enlightenment book)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I love the "DOM Enlightenment" book and wanted to read the companion volume for [jQuery](http://jqueryenlightenment.com/).

I have used basic jquery before such as below and I understand them..

```
$(document).bind(‘contextmenu’, function() {
    // do something
});
```

But book mentions something like below... and I don't understand how this gets used??

```
(function($){
// Use $ alias worry-free of conflicts
alert('You are using jQuery ' + $().jquery );
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: @Derek: No it's not.

Comment: Why did you have a tag node.js if this has nothing to do with node.js?

Comment: sorry, this was corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript anonymous(Functions without any name) functions can be there and to these functions are Immediately-Invoked

```
(function($){
    // Use $ alias worry-free of conflicts
    alert('You are using jQuery ' + $().jquery );
})(jQuery)
```

This is an anonymous Immediately-Invoked Function. And "$" is passed to this function and while invoking 'jQuery' is written. This is just to make it clear that '$' is denoting 'jQuery'. You can also use

```
(function(){
    // Use $ alias worry-free of conflicts
    alert('You are using jQuery ' + $().jquery );
})()
```

It will work fine.

$().jquery is used to get the version of the jquery we are using.

These anonymous functions are used when we want a specific code to run everytime unconditionally when page loads.

Comment: You mean `In javascript`, not `In jquery` don't you?

Comment: There's actually a [really good argument](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) against referring to these as "Self-invoked functions"; it boils down to "No, they're not SELF-invoked...".

Comment: @TML: There's also a really good argument against giving it a magical name such as IIFE. I've answered one question that misunderstood scope hiding by IIFE as being a magical property if IIFE instead of a property of all functions in javascript.

Comment: @slebetman Fair enough - but I think the idea of avoiding a specific name for them may be a ship that has already sailed; I'm retrenching that argument at the boundary of "let's at least use a name that accurately represents what's happening." :)

Comment: while I appreciate everyone's response and I am sure some are more accurate than others but for my limited knowledge, this answer resonates the best. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
console = $('#console');
console.append("<p>At the start of execution, does $ === jQuery? " +( ($ === jQuery)?"yes":"no")+ "</p>");
$ = function() {};
console.append("<p>After re-assignment, does $ === jQuery? " +( ($ === jQuery)?"yes":"no")+ "</p>");
(function($) {
  console.append("<p>Inside our IFFE, does $ === jQuery? " +( ($ === jQuery)?"yes":"no")+ "</p>");
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="console"></div>
```

This is an "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression" - sometimes called an "IIFE" ('iffy'); you're passing the global object `jQuery` into the IIFE where it gets bound to the name `$` - just in case some other script getting loaded is using `$` for its own purposes.

It's also not uncommon to see someone make sure that 'undefined' hasn't be redefined to be something other than the ECMAScript `undefined`, using the same technique:

```
(function($, undefined) {
   // first argument, the global 'jQuery', bound to $
   // there is no second argument, so the ECMAScript built-in type 'undefined'
   // will be bound here to the name 'undefined'.
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It's not merely just in case, lots of popular libraries, some older than jQuery, use `$`. A very common example is prototype.js.

Comment: Yeah, "just in case" was intended to be interpreted a bit tongue-in-cheek; honestly, NONE of them should have been using it, as "The dollar sign [was] intended for use only in mechanically
generated code" at the time most of these libraries were being built. This restriction has since been dropped from the spec, but it WAS there, at the time.

Comment: Prototype.js was originally designed to be used with code automatically generated by Rails (in the same manner that ASP auto-injects javascript everywhere). So technically, it was for use with mechanically generated code. That people started using prototype.js manually was due to the advent of Web2.0 which ushers fearlessness towards javascript programming.

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as an immediate function invocation and it's native JavaScript.

```
(
 // 1. define an anonymous function
 function(parameter1, parameter2) {
  // 2. this function is now an object
 }
)(argument1, argument2); // 3. invoke it with ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually we need to call function in some place for the code inside it to get executed.
But Immediately-invoked function are different.
which means you need not call this function anywhere for it to get executed.
it would get executed on its on.Adding (); at the end makes it to get executed immediately.